# Display posts of specific Category

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

Lets say for instance I only want to display posts that are assigned to BOTH categories 2 & 5.

I don't want to see posts that are only assigned to 2 OR 5.

Any way to do this?

or.. if its easier.. from both a specific category AND a specific tag

Answer (score 1):

In a wp_query (I assume that's what you're wanting).  You would use the following from the WP Class Reference for wp_query:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category__and' => array( 2, 5 ) ) );
```

For a category and a tag, I assume you could get away with (UNTESTED):

```
$args = array (
   'cat' => 2,
   'tag_id' => 5,
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

You can view all wp_query arguments on the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query